# SQL Query for new Policies added by month and state for a year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a more efficient way of adding to a temp table. Basically, for every State, I need to include all 12 months. I have a very manual way right now, to get it working, but There has to be a better way to load a temp table. Basically I need the value to increment 1-12, without doing it manually. Is there a trick to this?

```
CREATE TABLE #TempStateCounts(
STATE CHAR(2),
MONTHCOUNT INT,
MONTHVALUE INT
)
INSERT INTO #TempStateCounts
(
    STATE,
    MONTHCOUNT,
    MONTHVALUE
)
SELECT ABBREV, 0, 1 --January
FROM dbo.STATE_LOOKUP
WHERE ABBREV IN ('AR','IA','IL','IN','KS','KY','MN','MO','ND','NE','OH','OK','SD','VA','WI')
INSERT INTO #TempStateCounts
(
    STATE,
    MONTHCOUNT,
    MONTHVALUE 
)
SELECT ABBREV, 0, 2 --February
FROM dbo.STATE_LOOKUP
WHERE ABBREV IN ('AR','IA','IL','IN','KS','KY','MN','MO','ND','NE','OH','OK','SD','VA','WI')
INSERT INTO #TempStateCounts
(
    STATE,
    MONTHCOUNT,
    MONTHVALUE 
)
SELECT ABBREV, 0, 3 --March
FROM dbo.STATE_LOOKUP
WHERE ABBREV IN ('AR','IA','IL','IN','KS','KY','MN','MO','ND','NE','OH','OK','SD','VA','WI')
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the numbers using a recursive CTE and then cross join:

```
with cte as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from cte 
      where n < 12
     )
insert into #TempStateCounts (STATE, MONTHCOUNT, MONTHVALUE)
    select abbrev, 0, n
    from dbo.state_lookup sl cross join 
         cte;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. As soon as I can mark this as the correct answer, I will. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You only have 12 to do so a while is not out of the question. But you may want a numbers table in the future:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempStateCounts(
STATE CHAR(2),
MONTHCOUNT INT,
MONTHVALUE INT
)

declare @m int =1
while (@m<=12)
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO #TempStateCounts
   (
       STATE,
       MONTHCOUNT,
       MONTHVALUE
   )
   SELECT ABBREV, 0, @m
   FROM dbo.STATE_LOOKUP
   WHERE ABBREV IN ('AR','IA','IL','IN','KS','KY','MN','MO','ND','NE','OH','OK','SD','VA','WI')

   set @m=@m+1
END
```

Comment: I cannot believe I did not think about this. This will work. I have selected the CTE answer as the correct one, but this will definitely work. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's better to understand what Gordon posted. This may be the least efficient way of doing it, but it is effective to see the process. I prefer a cross join numbers builder or actually using a numbers table